# Logical judgement of Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using logical judgement in GEE. Here is my toy code:

```
    var aa = ee.Number(0);
    print(aa.neq(0) );
    print(aa.eq(0) );
    if (aa.eq(0)){
        print('01 is zeros');
    }
    if (aa.neq(0)){
        print('02 is not zeros');
    }
```

Rather simple, but I got the following feedback:

[image: Ridiculous feedback from above simple code]

Is there any recommended and STABLE logical judgement form in GEE?

By the way, this code doesn't work either; it returns the same feedback as shown in the figure.

```
var aa = ee.Number(0);

print(aa.neq(0) );
print(aa.eq(0) );

if (aa.eq(ee.Number(0))){
  print('01 is zeros');
}
if (aa.neq(ee.Number(0))){
  print('02 is not zeros');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) problem.

`aa.eq(0)` is *not yet evaluated* — it is a JavaScript object that *represents* a computation that hasn't been performed by Earth Engine yet. The `print` function automatically performs the evaluation and displays the response. JavaScript's `if` does not know about Earth Engine objects and will always consider them to be ‘true’.

Generally, you should try to keep things server-side as much as possible — this results in more efficient computations because you're not having to send separate requests to Earth Engine for the *next* part of the computation. The direct correspondence to `if` is `ee.Algorithms.If`, but it is rarely needed. Instead, you can use operations such as `filter`ing a collection.

When you *definitely need* a result to be used in JavaScript, you should call `evaluate` to fetch it:

```
aa.eq(0).evaluate(function (answer) {
  if (answer) {
    ...
  }
});
```

But, again, this is rarely needed and if you think you need it, there is likely a better way. (Unless you're writing user-interface code for an interactive EE app.)

Comment: A demo: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a0d5fa764a38841d60c45739dc2ca8d9

Comment: I believe `evaluate` needs to be called as a method of the object. For instance: `aa.eq(0).evaluate()`

Comment: @jdbcode Thanks, my mistake!

Comment: This answer helps a lot, thanks!